# Jquery color plugin NOT converting to transparent

Tags: jquery, css

well I've used this color plugin for my website. Its actually working but not completely. 
My links have no background color according to my styles. But when you hover on them, the background color gets changed using the jquery BUT after hovering off them, there must not be any background color remained but it does. The "stop animate" probably does not do what I am willing to. 
I actually want these links to have no background color at all. I know its simple, But just could not get it done. 
Here is my jquery code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {             
     $("#Menu div span label a").hover(function () {    
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#00aadd" }, 600);     
         }, function () {    
    $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "transparent" },400);});
});
```

The complete codes are right here. http://jsfiddle.net/hGmxP/34/.

By the way, If u see that Ive used many tags for these simple links,its because the website gonna be my portfolio and It needs to have many layers for the designing part.
So anything wrong in my codes ? And Thanks in advance

Comment: The color plugin can't animate to transparent. Try using `rgba` instead.

Comment: THX for that BUT rgba lack the support for lower versions of browsers !!!

Comment: animate opacity, later versions of jquery support just using "opacity" and automatically throws in -webkit- or -ms- or -moz- depending on the browser used, and also use filter's for really bad versions of IE

Comment: @bizzehdee `opacity` would affect the opacity of the element, not just the color

Comment: Use `rgba` Works in newer browsers. Don't worry about older browsers, they won't let you change opacity of a background color in any case.

Comment: yes Ive heard about but not tried that. Though running out of time, Ill figure out those you guys have pointed soon.

Comment: But why cant jquery directly support what Im simply willing to do ???  Its just about converting the background color to transparent or actually leaving it to what it was.

Comment: Why are you complaining to us? We didn't write jQuery. As everyone else has said, this is a situation where I wouldn't worry about the old browsers and use rgba instead of burning a lot of calories on this.

Comment: Well sort of, but not actually complaining to you my friend or anyone else. Anyway, I  appreciate commenting on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using CSS.   But I don't think it will work on IE

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
transition: all 0.6s ease;
```

You can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/76uGE/1/

Comment: Thanks for the effort PSU , I even tried what you did. BUT as it is CSS3, therefor NO SUPPORT IN IE 7, 8 and 9 unfortunately.

Comment: No problem. I also found this, maybe you didn't read it http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4372

Comment: I honestly did not. BUT thx for showing me PSU. Now Ive got to try for some other solution.